# count of continue dates using mysql select

Tags: mysql

Using this  query

```
    select FROM_UNIXTIME(updates.up_day, '%Y-%m-%d') date 
       ,employees.em_name from updates 
join employees on updates.up_employeeid=employees.em_id 
join options on updates.up_optionid=options.op_id 
where employees.em_team_id=12 and  
      year(curdate()) = year(FROM_UNIXTIME(updates.up_day)) and
      MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(updates.up_day))= MONTH(CURDATE()) and 
      options.op_name not in ("OFF","Holiday") ;
```

*Query edited*

Getting result like this

```
    | 2016-12-19 | Ravi  
    | 2016-12-18 | Ravi 
    | 2016-12-25 | Ravi  
    | 2016-12-26 | Ravi  
    | 2016-12-27 | Ravi  
    | 2016-12-02 | Amith             
    | 2016-12-03 | Amith 
    | 2016-12-09 | Amith 
    | 2016-12-19 | Amith
    | 2016-12-18 | Amith
```

But we want result like

```
2  | Ravi 
3  | Ravi
2  | Amith
2  | Amith
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: Can you explain how the output is computed?

Comment: That ain't how we roll. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT mydate, myname,
       @seq := IF(@name = myname && DATEDIFF(mydate, @date) = 1, @seq + 1, 1),
       @name := myname,
       @date := mydate                 
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @date := '1900-01-01', @name := '', @seq := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY myname, mydate
```

`mytable` is your query, that is being used as a subquery. The query uses variables in order to calculate the rank of consecutive records. The rank is incremented by one in case the two consecutive records share the same name value and have exactly one day as difference.

**Note:** You should use nested conditionals in order to assign values to `@name` and `@date` variables. I have left this piece out of my query for the sake of simplicity.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57aaee/2)